# I need to expect multi value with if statement

Tags: qgis, postgresql, sql

I have field called `name` which has values like `Ahmed and Marten`.
I need to check if this is the title without considering `and`.

The answer is `no` for `if(name is title(name) ,'yes','no')` because of `and`.
So I need to get `yes` in the QGIS query.

Comment: Welcome to GIS Se. Sorry, your question is unclear. You want to delete `and` from `Ahmed and Marten`? You can do this using the `replace()` function.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please take a [tour] to learn how the site works.

Answer (score 5):

You need to replace `' and'` with `''`. E.g. `Ahmed and Marten` -> `Ahmed Marten`, and then check `replaced_name is title(replaced_name)`.

Use this expression:

```
with_variable(
    'text',  -- variable name
    replace("name", 'and ', ''), -- replace 'and ' with ''
    if ( @text is title(@text),  'yes', 'no' )
)
```

`Ahmed and Marten` -> yes
`Ahmed and marten` -> no
`ahmed and Marten` -> no
`ahmed and marten` -> no

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly.
But try something like:

```
if( strpos( 'the name you are searching for' , "name" ) > 0 , 'yes' , 'no' )
```